# heroku and neo4j access via a Java servlet

Tags: java, heroku, neo4j

I am getting started using Heroku and Neo4j. I have a servlet which runs locally to insert some nodes and create a relationship between them. When I use the same code at Heroku I get no error but just nothing happens.

I have tried inserting nodes manually using webadmin at Neo4j and then reading it back in the code and again it works locally but at Heroku nothing happens. Again there is no error message.

Here is the code:

```
String dbPATH = System.getenv("NEO4J_URL")+"/db/data";
String dbName = "/mnt/e67f2f314/data/graph.db";
String dbLoc = dbPATH+dbName;
GraphDb=new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(dbLoc);
```

Then I use:

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(GraphDb);
int length=-1;
try{
    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start n=node(*) return n");
    if (result == null){
        length = 0;
    } else
    {
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Map<String, Object> row:result){
                length++;   
            }
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
//  _log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    length=-2;
}
```

The length is 0, hence a null object is returned. I am using heroku run bash and then java -cp to run the jar file.

heroku config:
NEO4J_URL:                   http://xxx:xxx@e67f2f314.hosted.neo4j.org:

I have tried a few variations on the dbLoc which is passed to newEmbeddedDatabase and nothing has worked.

I would appreciate any links on implementing Java and Neo4j at Heroku for running a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j on Heroku is accessible by REST only, so you cannot use embedded. Therefore you need to amend the following dependency to your application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>[your version]</version>
</dependency>
```

Initializing is as follows:

```
RestAPI restAPI = new RestAPIFacade(System.getenv("NEO4J_URL"), 
   System.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"), 
   System.getenv("NEO4J_PASSWORD"));
GraphDatabaseService gds = new RestGraphDatabase(restAPI);
RestCypherQueryEngine rcqe = RestCypherQueryEngine(restAPI);
```

Then just execute your cypher statements using `rcqe.query()`.

Comment: I haven't found a repository yet with the Java Binding for Neo4j's REST api. So in order for it to work with heroku, I had to create a project-specific repository for the binding and add it to my project like that.

Comment: Thanks :) Makes it a lot easier to use the binding. Btw, you don't happen to know a way so that  you don't have to copy all the dependencies in your target folder?